# The proper way to write the input for a certain series

Tags: summation

Mathematica tells the series below doesn't converge. I think it converges. What would the 
proper way to write things be as an input?

```
Sum[((-1)^(n) Log[1 + 2 n])/(1 + 2 n), {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

Comment: By the alternating series test it's clear the series converges, but it seems the convergence is very slow.

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?  It doesn't tell me that it does not converge.  It simply can't calculate it.  v9.0.1 here.

Comment: @Szabolcs I use v8.0 here.

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce that in v8.  It seems it was a bug in v9, 'fixed' in a certain way in v9.  No answer is better than a wrong answer.

Comment: Mathematica 9 knows it converges, just cannot find a closed form. `In[367]:= SumConvergence[((-1)^(n) Log[1 + 2 n])/(1 + 2 n), n]

Out[367]= True`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I'm somewhat surprised to see Mathematics v8.0 is not able to provide with a correct answer. I was thinking my input is not correct.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau ["Mathematica 9 knows it converges"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animism) - You may consider talking to someone. :D

Comment: @belisarius We've been talking to ourself for days now...

Comment: Maybe it's time people from Wolfram improve their software ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can sum your infinite series by shifting the sum over `n` along by `1/2`, which then simplifies the summand to a form that Mathematica can handle.

```
(1/(-1)^(1/2)) Sum[((-1)^n Log[2 n])/(2 n), {n, 1/2, Infinity, 1}]

(* (1/4) (Pi Log[4] + StieltjesGamma[1, 1/4] - StieltjesGamma[1, 3/4]) *)
```

The overall factor `1/(-1)^(1/2)` cancels the `(-1)^(1/2)` factor that is introduced by shifting the sum in this way.

Numerically this evaluates to `-0.192901`, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

To get an actual answer in this case, you could simply retreat to the numerical evaluation of this sum. It works by simply changing `Sum` to `NSum` in your code:

```
NSum[((-1)^(n) Log[1 + 2 n])/(1 + 2 n), {n, 0, Infinity}]

(* ==> -0.192901 *)
```